# How get user info from facebook via API?

Tags: ruby, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I'm developing API to integrate rails app with Facebook.

I receive from client only:

```
{
  provider:     'facebook',
  user_id:      'USER_ID',
  access_token: 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
}
```

But I need create user and save it into database if user is not registered etc. I have models `user` and `authentication` (user has many authentications):

```
class User
  validate :first_name, :last_name, :email, 
           presense: true 

  has_many :providers
endd

class Authentication
  validate :provider, :user_id, :access_token, :refresh_token, :expires_at, 
           presense: true

  belongs_to :user
end
```

Facebook app is already created and all permissions are set up correctly.

Problem:

To save user with authentication into DB - I need to have all fields.

Question:

If I have `provider`, `user_id` and `access_token`, 
  how can I get additional fields: 
  `email`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `refresh_token` and `expires_at`.

Which API request should I make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using oauth2. If so, you should be able to use the [`/me` route](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3). The [graph api overview page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview) is also pretty helpful.

Have you considered omniauth? It's very easy to set up as well as expanding identity providers like [facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook), twitter, or google. If nothing else looking through the [facebook omniauth gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/blob/master/lib/omniauth/strategies/facebook.rb#L58) might help you out.